# find a pair of elements with the same value with the largest distance between the elements

Tags: c, arrays, runtime, element

I have an array of 'N' double values but I am trying to find a pair of the same elements that have the furthest distance between them.

So as an example;

```
{1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 1}
Output: (1,1) has the largest distance between them
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I approach this because I am completely stumped?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: More like "find a pair of elements with the same value"

Comment: Compare 1st to 2nd, 3rd, 4th ...., then 2nd to 1st, 3rd, 4th,... then 3rd to 1st, 2nd, 4th,...  and so on. If the same value, rate the distance.  That is a simple solution, not efficient, yet simply enough to get you off the "I am completely stumped".

Comment: Any idea on how i would go about doing that?

Comment: Adam, surely you have written _some_ code for this.  Post what you have tried to improve the question.

Comment: I genuinely have nothing and that's why I came on here for help

Answer (score 0):

Here are my five cents.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 1 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t first = 0, last = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N - ( last - first ); i++ )
    {
        size_t j = N;
        while ( --j != i && a[j] != a[i] );

        if ( j != i )
        {
            if ( last - first < j - i )
            {
                first = i;
                last = j;
            }
        }
    }

    if ( first != last )
    {
        printf( "%d: ( %zu, %zu )\n", a[first], first, last );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1: ( 0, 10 )
```

The loops can be more optimized if to include the following condition

```
    if ( i == 0 || a[i] != a[last] )
```

to skip values that were already considered.

Here is the program with this if statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 1 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t first = 0, last = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N - ( last - first ); i++ )
    {
        if ( i == 0 || a[i] != a[last] )
        {
            size_t j = N;
            while ( --j != i && a[j] != a[i] );

            if ( j != i )
            {
                if ( last - first < j - i )
                {
                    first = i;
                    last = j;
                }
            }
        }           
    }

    if ( first != last )
    {
        printf( "%d: ( %zu, %zu )\n", a[first], first, last );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the same program in which a test output is inserted to show how often the inner loop is executed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t first = 0, last = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N - ( last - first ); i++ )
    {
        if ( i == 0 || a[i] != a[last] )
        {
            printf( "Inner loop for %d\n", a[i] );

            size_t j = N;
            while ( --j != i && a[j] != a[i] );

            if ( j != i )
            {
                if ( last - first < j - i )
                {
                    first = i;
                    last = j;
                }
            }
        }           
    }

    if ( first != last )
    {
        printf( "%d: ( %zu, %zu )\n", a[first], first, last );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Inner loop for 1
Inner loop for 2
2: ( 4, 8 )
```

So the inner loop is executed only two times.

Comment: this outputs (0,10) but i am trying to find a pair of same elements to find the distance between them

Comment: @Adam The output shows the value that is repeated and indices in which the value is repeated. 1: ( 0, 10 ). So the difference 10 - 0 gives the maximum distance in the array. Having the values first and last you can output what you want. What is the problem?!

Comment: my apologies i was mistaken i understand now thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Code could try every pair.

Yet a key is to avoid testing pairs that are less than the current known max distance.

```
size_t max_common_element_distance(size_t n, const double *x) {
  size_t max_distance = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (size_t j = i+1; j + max_distance < n; j++) {
      // test beyond the max distance for a better one.
      if (x[i] == x[j + max_distance]) {
        max_distance = j + max_distance - i;
        // Perhaps record other info here, like the index of the 2 elements 
        // to use as part of the "Output: ..." report
      }
    }
  }
  return max_distance;
}
```

Better code would run the `j` loop in the opposite direction, from `n-max_distance-1` down t `i+1`.  But is sounds like OP needs a good, not so complex, starting point.

---

Deeper:  The order of complexity above is `O(n*n)`.  A `O(n*log(n))` solution exists by forming a list of (value, index) pairs, sort it by value (and then by index on ties), then walk the list once to find the max index difference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  double value;
  size_t index;
} pair;

int pair_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
  const pair *pa = a;
  const pair *pb = b;
  int cmp = (pa->value > pb->value) - (pa->value < pb->value);
  if (cmp == 0) {
    cmp = (pa->index > pb->index) - (pa->index < pb->index);
  }
  return cmp;
}

size_t max_common_element_distance(size_t n, const double *x) {
  size_t max_distance = 0;
  if (n > 0) {
    pair y[n];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      y[i].index = i;
      y[i].value = x[i];
    }
    qsort(y, n, sizeof y[0], pair_cmp);
    size_t from, to;
    size_t first = 0;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      if (y[i].value == y[first].value) {
        size_t distance = y[i].index - y[first].index;
        if (distance > max_distance) {
          max_distance = distance;
          from = y[first].index;
          to = y[i].index;
        }
      } else {
        first = i;
      }
    }
    if (max_distance > 0) {
      printf("from:%zu to:%zu dist:%zu val:%g\n", from, to, max_distance, x[from]);
    }
  }
  return max_distance;
}

int main() {
  double val[] = {1, 3, 5, 3, 7, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7, 1};
  size_t n = sizeof val/ sizeof val[0];
  max_common_element_distance(n, val);
}
```

Output

```
from:0 to:10 dist:10 val:1
```